# XPath for elements with class attribute value not containing a given substring?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

For following structure I need to match only those divs which are not children of the div with class `styled__MobileWrapper-sc-mljlp8-0`. The class name is generated with only the `MobileWrapper` part being static, so I can't match the whole class name, but only its substring.

```
<div>
    <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
    <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
    <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="styled__MobileWrapper-sc-mljlp8-0 jnegik">
        <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
        <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
        <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="styled__DesktopWrapper-sc-mljlp8-2">
        <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
        <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
        <div data-testid="product-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would imagine something along these lines would work: `//div[not(contains(@class, 'MobileWrapper'))]/div[@data-testid='product-container']`, but it still matches all product-containers, probably because it compares the whole class name and not looking for substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath,

```
//div[not(contains(@class, 'MobileWrapper'))]
```

selects all `div` elements without a `@class` attribute value that has a substring of `'MobileWrapper'`.  It includes `div` elements that do not have a `class` attribute at all.

This XPath,

```
//div[@class[not(contains(.,'MobileWrapper'))]]
```

will select only those `div` elements with a `class` attribute whose value does not contain a `'MobileWrapper'` substring.

You may append `/div[@data-testid='product-container']` to select only those targeted `div` elements children..